# Fetching Friends from api and Display on the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

i'M working on a **Chat Application project**

but im getting this error of fetching friends from the backend(node)

I'm getting the friends data on the console but i'm unable to display it.

this is my **Context** and **States**

```
 export const Messenger = () => {
  // Context State
  const { friends, setFriends, authInfo } = useAuth();
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState();
  const { updateNotification } = useNotification();

  const fetchMessengerUsers = async () => {
    try {
      const token = getToken();
      const config = {
        headers: {
          authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        },
      };
      const { data } = await client("/get-friends", config);
      console.log(data);
      setFriends(data);
    } catch (error) {
      updateNotification("error", "Failed To load the Chat");
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoggedUser(localStorage.getItem("auth-token"));
    fetchMessengerUsers();
  }, []);
```

then in **return** i'm **mapping** all friends to display them

```
<div className="friends">
          {friends && friends.length > 0
            ? friends.map((fd) => (
                <div className="hover-friend">
                  <Friends friend={fd} />
                </div>
              ))
            : "No Friend"}
        </div>
```

It displays **No Friend** on the browser

[this link shows how it appears on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W42J4.png)

Comment: you mean `setFriends(data.friends);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your fetchMessengerUsers function.

you need to set setFriends(data.friends)

```
      const fetchMessengerUsers = async () => {
        try {
          const token = getToken();
          const config = {
            headers: {
              authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            },
          };
          const { data } = await client("/get-friends", config);
          console.log(data);

          setFriends(data.friends); // you have to set friends array here, earlier you were setting the entire object.
        } catch (error) {
          updateNotification("error", "Failed To load the Chat");
        }
      };
```